# error message whwn trying to create an s3 bucket policy in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

i have typed the code to create the bucket and edited the bucket policy but it keeps giving the error message api error "invalid principal in policy"

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowS3ReadAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::165900692356:role/S3DynamoDBFullAccessRole"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::employee-photo-bucket-al-752",
                "arn:aws:s3:::employee-photo-bucket-al-752/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

above is the code i expected the bucket to be created

Comment: Does that role exist?

Comment: yes it does i created it a couple of days ago, do you think i should delete the role

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add a `Principal` to an [identity based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html)?

You must use the `Principal` element in resource-based policies. Several services support resource-based policies, including IAM. The IAM resource-based policy type is a role trust policy. In IAM roles, use the Principal element in the role trust policy to specify who can assume the role.